# Dual boot OS X 10.7/10.8 with File Vault and encrypted backup

Tags: backup, osx-lion, multi-boot, filevault, osx-mountain-lion

**Mac Mini Core i5-2520M (mid 2011 model) plus external Fire Wire Freecom 1GB drive**

Current:

- Vanilla setup - ie.  a single visible OSX 10.7 (Lion) partition plus hidden recovery partition
- File Vault switched off (understand this is File Vault 2 in Lion)
- Simple unecrypted Time Machine backup to FireWire drive
- Used for standard dev work with XCode for IOS/OSX

Want:

- Dual boot OSX 10.7 (Lion) & 10.8 (Mountain Lion)
- File Vault 2, or some other whole disk encryption, switched on
- Encrypted Time Machine backup to Firewire drive
- Alternative encrypted bootable backups to Firewire drive
- Manual rotation of backups to multiple Firewire drives

Progress so far:

- Repartioned external Firewire drive to 3 HFS+ partions
- Renamed 2nd partion to "TIME MACHINE" for Time Machine backups
- Purchased Super Duper for bootable backups
- Renamed 3rd partion to "SUPER DUPER" for Super Duper backups

Uncertain things:

- Whether File Vault 2 will cut it for dual boot OSX10.7/10.8
- How partions will be identified by backup programs - ie. human readable name or partion id - and how this affects rotation of FireWire drives
- Best (reasonably safe) order to proceed from here

What's the best way to achieve something like the desired setup?

Thanks in advance for any advice!